# Create an new package type maven and use it in tomcat project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I've created a new parent project with child module

- OldParent
- Parent

  - Child 1
    =========>pom.xml
  - Child 2
    =========>pom.xml
  - Lib   =========>pom.xml

  ======>pom.xml

======>pom.xml

I have created module "Lib" with a new extension package ".ria"
See below pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyProjectId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Lib</artifactId>
  <packaging>ria</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
    <--------------------My archetype project ---------------->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>MyProjectGroupeId</groupId>
        <artifactId>xx-archetype</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Child 1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Child 2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have my parent one pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyProjectGroupeId</groupId>
    <artifactId>OldParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>MyProjectId</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Common service for business solution</name>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>Child 1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>Child 2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
  <modules>
    <module>Child 1</module>
    <module>Child 2</module>
    <module>Lib</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

I have declared in my tomcat project dependencies for Lib project

```
<!-- Module dependencies  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyProjectId</groupId>
      <artifactId>Lib</artifactId>
      <version>${lib.version}</version>
      <type>ria</type>
    </dependency>
```

I have all dependecies Child1 and Child2 in my Maven dependencies
but i have this error when i will do maven install my Tomcat project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xx-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project MyProjectGroupeId:xx-server:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at MyProjectId:Lib:ria:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for MyProjectId:Lib:ria:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT Could not find artifact MyProjectGroupeId:OldParent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you did not install `MyProjectId:Lib:ria:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` in your repository.

Try `mvn install` in this project directory, and retry.

Also checks if it exists in the `~/.m2/repository`.

Comment: Hi,i'have all jar for Child1,Child 2 and new extension for my Lib project in my ~/.m2/repository.

Comment: I' ve just need to install my MyProjectGroupeId:OldParent

Comment: The error means the dependency could not be found, and since you don't seem to use a maven repository such as Nexus or Archiva, I only expect it to _not_ be in the local repository. The install command will do that. Also, read the link provided by the maven error: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Comment: Ok, thank you.I've forgotten to install parent project